# Insert accented arbitrary characters into ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to insert a letter with the ^ symbol above the letter into a ggplot title, e.g. p-hat (but formated).

I've tried:

```
x <- seq(1:6)
y <- x^2
z <- rep(c("theta","gamma"),3)
xyz <- data.frame(x,y,z)

ggplot(xyz, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=z)) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(expression(p-hat)))
```

But this just labels it literally.

Can't get a clear glossary or info on how in general to accent arbitrary Roman characters for R plots, other than specific characters used in e.g. French or Spanish. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R plotmath has both a `hat` and a `widehat` function. If you wanted to move the annotation over to the right you can use as many tildes as needed

```
x <- seq(1:6)
y <- x^2
z <- rep(c("theta","gamma"),3)
xyz <- data.frame(x,y,z)

ggplot(xyz, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=z)) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(expression( hat(p) )))

ggplot(xyz, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=z)) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(expression( widehat(p) )))

ggplot(xyz, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=z)) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(expression( ~~~~~~~widehat(p) )))
```

See `?plotmath`

Answer (score 2):

Try `expression(hat(p))` for your argument to `guide_legend()`.